# How to style input fields of a specific HTML form with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, styling, input-field

I am trying to style the following form.

```
<form onSubmit={this.updateUserInformation} id="userInfoForm">
                    <label>First Name</label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" value="John"></input><br></br>
                    <label>Last Name</label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" value="Maloy"></input><br></br>
                    <label>Username</label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" value="John"></input><br></br>
                    <label>Password</label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" value="Maloy"></input><br></br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update My Info"></input>
                </form>
```

Please ignore my values; I will be adding dynamic info later. 
The issue is that I have several forms on my web page, so I don't want to create a style on my css file for the input tag as it would style all my input fields the same. It there a way to style all the input fields of a form based on the id of the **form** without having to add an id to every individual input field?
For example, here is my css file style for the form that is not quite working:

```
#userInfoForm {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    input {
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
}
```

My logic behind this is to style each input within the identified form. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use the attribute selector to target a specific input element.

Comment: The css that you have written targets all inputs inside the form. Use class or attribute name as identifier to target specific css.

Comment: are u using scss ? It's seems the code written in scss style (nesting input {})

Comment: use 'input' out of #userInfoForm boundary. style #userInfoForm {} & #userInfoForm input{ } individually for css. for scss your code is okey.

Answer (score 0):

> You can style an specific input field here by a unique portion. Which will enable you to style specific input (possible if have uniqueness) without **`id`** or **`class`**

**Example:**
You have three input fields -

```
 - <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
 - <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
 - <input type="pass" name="password" value="" />
```

the uniqueness between three is name. That are `[name="username"]`, `[name="email"]`, `[name="password"]` (where [type="text"] will select first two input element, value="" is discarded because it can have random value)

**This is for if you want for a specific form all inputs are different looking**
So, can apply as -

```
#userInfoForm {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  [name="username"]{
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  [name="email"]{
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  [name="password"]{
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
}
```

**Another way**

if the number of input fields are predefined in a form, can use child selector

```
 #userInfoForm {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  input {
    &:nth-child(1) {
       border-radius: 20px;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
       border-radius: 25px;
    }
  }
}
```

**This is for if you want for a different form inputs are different looking as form wise** (but for a specific form all inputs are same, different form's inputs are different)

```
 #userInfoForm input {
   background-color: red;
}
 #userInfoForm2 input {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer. It styled each input field of my identified form without having to add an ID to each field. This is similar to the attribute selector mentioned above in the comments.

```
#userInfoForm {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FF6700;
    border-radius: 25px; 
}

#userInfoForm input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```